# using Cloud Firestore Database API to create cloud firestore database with`database_id` of '(default)' not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

I used Google.Apis.Firestore.v1 library to create a cloud firestore for my firebase project as follows, but when running my code I am getting an error related to the database naming I guess, and it has a regular expression format as shown in the error below, and how can I fix this issue?

```
using Google.Apis.Firestore.v1;

private static FirestoreService _firestoreService;
public static void IntializeFirestoreAdmin() {
   GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
   if (CloudManager.Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
   {
       credential = CloudManager.Credential.CreateScoped(FirestoreService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
            }
       _firestoreService = new FirestoreService(
        new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {                 
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = CloudManager.ApplicationName

        });          
            

        }
 public static void AddCloudFirestore() {
       IntializeFirestoreAdmin();
       var mydata = new GoogleFirestoreAdminV1Database {
                LocationId = "nam5",
                Type = "FIRESTORE_NATIVE",
                Name = "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/databases/(default)",
                
            };
      _firestoreService.Projects.Databases.Create(mydata, "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId).Execute();
}
```

Error :

```
Unhandled exception. The service firestore has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is BadRequest.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
database_id should be 4-63 characters, and valid characters are /[a-z][0-9]-/ [400]
Errors [
    Message[database_id should be 4-63 characters, and valid characters are /[a-z][0-9]-/] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service firestore has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. database_id should be 4-63 characters, and valid characters are /[a-z][0-9]-/
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
```

Comment: can you provide which documentation you are following ?

Comment: I referred from the rest api description I found and trying to code it in c#, I used this google doc link https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1#google.firestore.admin.v1.Database

Comment: If you see in doc  `projects/{project}/databases/{database}` as the database name so your database_id will be `projects/{project}/databases/(default)` but in your case you are replicating it twice

Comment: I don't understand Rohit where I replicated it, because I only provided the database_id for the name field once, which is                 Name = "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/databases/(default)",

Comment: what is the type of your CloudManager.ProjectId I mean in this way : project-xxxxxxx because it should satisfy the naming convention for database_id : [naming-convention](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1#createdatabaserequest)

Comment: CloudManager.ProjectId is a string data type which holds a value of my project id. Okay so my projectid for instance when I am testing it is mydev6project9 , and what you are saying is the project id has a naming convention , and that the one I am using doesn't satisfy it, is that the case?

Comment: yes that is what I am suggesting if possible can you also show the imports for the modules you used by editing your question ?

Comment: I have added the library I used in the code section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var body = new GoogleFirestoreAdminV1Database
{
    Type = "FIRESTORE_NATIVE",
    LocationId = "nam5"
};
string parent = $"projects/{CloudManager.ProjectId}";
var request = _firestoreService.Projects.Databases.Create(body, parent);
request.DatabaseId = "(default)";
var response = request.Execute();
```

The issue was that I didn't add the databaseId as a query parameter. For more details go to this link https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/EQ-04MnPyLk

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the given [method](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/create) :

`FirestoreService().Projects.Databases.Create` it has `parent` as Parameter and `databaseId` as a Query parameter there is also a try this method section where you can verify your parameters are correct like for example :

```
using Google.Apis.Firestore.v1;

private static FirestoreService _firestoreService;
public static void IntializeFirestoreAdmin() {
   GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
   if (CloudManager.Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
   {
       credential = CloudManager.Credential.CreateScoped(FirestoreService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
            }
       _firestoreService = new FirestoreService(
        new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {                 
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = CloudManager.ApplicationName

        });          
            

        }
 public static void AddCloudFirestore() {
       IntializeFirestoreAdmin();
       var mydata = new GoogleFirestoreAdminV1Database {
                LocationId = "nam5",
                Type = "FIRESTORE_NATIVE",
                Name = "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/databases/my-database",
                
            };
      _firestoreService.Projects.Databases.Create(mydata, "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId).Execute();
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing, I have followed the naming convention,  I passed projects/myprojectid for the project and for the database databases/(default). And the error still persists.

Comment: Change Name assignment to like this ```Name = "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId + "/databases/my-database"``` Where my-database can your database name of choice, basically name anything but following with that naming convensions.

Comment: Hey Rohit, I used as your recommendation  , Name =  $"projects/{CloudManager.ProjectId}/databases/my-database" but still the error persisted. I really have no idea why I am having this same error repeatedly.

Comment: @Samaritan have you tried the one I have shared above just ignore this ans and make your Name variable that I have shared means replace (default) with my-database

Comment: Yes I tried it now with another random names as well based on the format you shared, but still the error didn't go  away. For instance, now i tried it with the following database name     Name =  $"projects/{CloudManager.ProjectId}/databases/profive-store"

Comment: Hi updated the code as per the changes required